# Can we use Jfree chart in Jasper server or Ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jfreechart, jasperserver

I am trying to use Jfree charts in Jasper server or Ireport, can we do that? If yes how can use Jfree chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports

There are some Samples.

Take a look at the JFreeChart Sample.